# How to add custom HTTP response header in Flask-RESTful?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I am using Flask-RESTful and would like to handle certain errors by adding a custom HTTP header to my response.  Is there a standard Flask or Flask-RESTful way of doing this?

Comment: Have you read http://flask-restful-cn.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/quickstart.html?

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe.  I missed that part.

Answer (score 9):

Turns out I skipped over that part of the docs:

```
class Todo3(Resource):
    def get(self):
        # Set the response code to 201 and return custom headers
        return {'task': 'Hello world'}, 201, {'Etag': 'some-opaque-string'}
```