# Flask fails to add custom headers

Tags: python, http, flask

I'm trying to return custom headers like this:

```
@app.route("/generate", methods=['POST'])
def generate():
    # data is generated here
    resp = Response(jsonify(data))
    resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = True
    return resp
```

But they don't seem to be present in the output.
Changing status code to 201 as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080310/how-to-add-custom-http-response-header-in-flask-restful) didn't help either (I did this by adding `status=201` to `Responce` construction).

Any bit of help would be appreciated.

EDIT 1:
Added a bit to a code.
Solutions described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25860304/how-do-i-set-response-headers-in-flask) didn't work for me either. Tried both `Response` and `make_response`, added `@app.after_request` as suggested - no effect.
The only headers present are:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
'Content-Length': '113', 
'Server': 'Werkzeug/1.0.1 Python/3.7.7', 
'Date': 'Fri, 08 May 2020 17:05:38 GMT'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that, although you are adding custom headers, you are still returning a JSON object where you write `resp = Response(jsonify(data))`. It is possible that flask assingns the response headers automatically based on the response's body's format.